# How to cope with bad sector on a portable storage

Tags: partitioning, badblocks

I have a WD portable hard drive working as day to day backup. Recently there seems to have some read/write error on specific files and smells like bad sector problem.

I am using `ddrescue` to do data backup to a new hard drive. What I don't know is how to cope with the old drive. Since the `ddrescue` don't show quite a lot bad sectors in its result, I want to quarantine them and use the rest healthy space.

I did some googling and find some tool mentioned like `e2fsck`, `fsck` and `badblocks`. The first 2 tries to fix the bad sectors, the 3rd locate bad block id. However, what if the `fsck` can't repair the error? In some [article](https://superuser.com/questions/77789/external-hard-drive-bad-sectors-recover-mark-utility-in-linux) it is indicated `badblocks`

> force the drive itself to remap any problematic sectors

But I doubt how that is achieved, especially when the hard drive is connected to another PC with Windows OS.

Per my understanding I need to make partitions on the drive, leave some blank area between these partitions and make sure all the bad sectors locate in these blank area. Is my understanding correct? Are there any recommended tool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Bad blocks can not be repaired. They are added to a special blacklistlist of bad blocks to be avoided in the future. This is done by using `sudo e2fsck -c /dev/sdXY` on an existing partition with a linux file system. There is no need to make special partitions, or leave blanks pace.

Here is a quote from `man e2fsck`

```
    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
    read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
    If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block in‐
    ode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or directory.
    If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan  will
    be done using a non-destructive read-write test.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So after `e2fsck`, the hard drive controller itself can "mark" and "replace" the bad sectors? I am wondering where these info are stored inside the hard drive.

Comment: No, `e2fsck -c` essentially tells the kernel which blocks should be avoided/blacklisted. The HDD controller has an independent way of detecting and reallocation bad sectors. The info is likely stored in a text file.

Comment: That is what I am worrying. After I run `e2fsck` on a Ubuntu, then move it to another Windows machine, the latter won't have knowledge on where the bad sectors are and will still read/write on those, make things worse.

Comment: Since you've mentioned a Windows machine, the filesystem on that HDD is probably NTFT or exfat, and so `e2fsck` won't work. If that is the case, you might need to search for a similar tool for Windows.

Comment: If we just consider `EXT4` file system. Running `e2fsck` for a portable drive in one Ubuntu machine then connect it to the second Ubuntu machine, will the second one get knowledge of the failure sectors?